# jQuery TableSorter Remember Sort Preferences?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is it possible to somehow store or cache sort preferences. Even if I can store them into a php session or anything where I can associate the current search (it's returning search results) and it's sort preferences so I can go back and see stuff in order...

Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well you can specify a sort when you set up the tablesorter, like this:

```
$("table").tablesorter({         
      // sort on the first column and third column, order asc         
      sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]]     
});
```

So if you store that object and pass it to the sortList option, sure!

Comment: @Brandon, add a comment or update your own question if you want to ask further questions. Don't add more questions inside answers, it is very hard to follow what is a question and what is an answer if you do so.

Answer (score 2):

I have a `saveSort` widget included with my fork of tablesorter; it saves the sort to local storage with a cookie fallback; it will work with the original plugin, just include the `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js` file and add the widget id to the initialization code: [demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html)

```
$("table").tablesorter({ 
  widgets: ["saveSort"] 
});
```